# bsoncxx - is there a way to iterate through documents in .bson dump file?

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

Similarly to how we construct bsoncxx::document::view objects from a buffer with a single binary document, is there a way to extract single documents from a collection in a .bson dump in this framework without having to load them into a DB?

i.e. what works for single document objects

```
uint8 *buffer; // single bson document
size_t length; // size of buffer
bsoncxx::document::view view(buffer, length);

for (auto elem : view) {
doSomethingWithElem()
}
```

I'd like to be able to construct a cursor for the whole dump, but without loading it into a collection. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution and it was pretty simple in the end - I utilized the libbson library.
An example of what I used below:

```
#include <bson.h>
// and other includes

void read_bson() {

    bson_reader_t *reader;
    const bson_t *doc;
    bson_error_t error;
    bool eof;
    char *path;

    reader = bson_reader_new_from_file(path, &error);

if (reader)
        {
            while ((doc = bson_reader_read(reader, &eof)))
            {
                  const uint8_t *buffer = bson_get_data(doc);
                  auto view = bsoncxx::document::view(buffer, doc->len);
             }
         }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this looks about right to me. I think you asked the same question on mongodb-user, so I'm happy you got to a solution you like. I personally wasn't aware of bson_reader_new_from_file. I do think that my caveats on mongodb-user are still valid though: I don't think there is any promise that the internal format produced by mongodump will always be the same as what the bson_reader_t subsystem consumes. In practice though, you are probably fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mongo-cxx-driver, here is a example for reading bson file dumped by mongodump tool.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/uri.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
#include <sstream>

void parse_one_doc(const char *data, const size_t &length) {
    // TODO fill your code
    bsoncxx::document::view view((std::uint8_t *) data, length);
    std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(view) << std::endl;
}

int unpack_size(const char *data, size_t position) {
    return *(int *) (data + position);
}

bool parse_mongo_dumper(const std::string &data) {
    size_t position = 0u, end = data.length() - 1u, data_len = data.size();
    size_t obj_size, obj_end;
    const char *dc = data.c_str();
    while (position < end) {
        obj_size = unpack_size(dc, position);
        if (position + obj_size > data_len) {
            return false;
        }

        obj_end = position + obj_size;
        if (*(dc + obj_end - 1) != '\0') {
            return false;
        }

        parse_one_doc(dc + position, obj_size);
        position = obj_end;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    std::string f = "/path/to/data.bson";
    // read all data into string
    std::ifstream t(f);
    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << t.rdbuf();
    std::string s = buffer.str();

    // parse bson
    parse_mongo_dumper(s);
    return 0;
}
```